# PowerPC GCC Relocation Operators

Tags: gcc, assembly, cross-platform, gnu-assembler, powerpc

I found Greenhills compiler for power pc , has some relocation expression operators like:

```
%lo(value): Least significant 16 bits of symbol value.
%hiadj(value) :Most significant 16 bits of symbol value plus most significant
bit of %lo(value).
```

I checked the GAS manual for V850 target, I found below :

```
lo() :Computes the lower 16 bits of the given expression and stores it into the immediate
operand field of the given instruction. 
hi() :Computes the higher 16 bits of the given expression and then adds the value
of the most significant bit of the lower 16 bits of the expression and stores the
result into the immediate operand field of the given instruction.
```

However I don't find any similar things for powerpc target in GAS manual . Is there any one know what is the equivalent ones for powerpc target for GCC? if there is no equivalent opcode or operator what is the equivalent assembly? Thank you !

**Update:**

Got green hills license and tried:
The source code from Greenhills project in one C file:

```
__asm__(e_lis       sp, %hiadj(stack_address);                )
__asm__(e_add16i    sp,sp,%lo(stack_address);/* stack_address is one variable from link command file*/)
```

The object dump from the O file and temporary S file from compilation is the same like below :

```
e_lis       sp, %hiadj(stack_address);
e_add16i    sp,sp,%lo(stack_address);
```

When I check the binary map file and the object dump of the binary, I got the below information:

```
 stack_address = 400b6400

 90001a4:   70 28 e0 0b     e_lis   r1,16395
 90001a8:   1c 21 64 00     e_add16i r1,r1,25600
```

You can see clearly, actually, 16395 = 0x400b, 25600 = 0x6400, so basically, the %lo and %hiadj are done by the Greenhills that's why GCC doesn't have them. 
I assume GCC has the same Marco or operator to do that same thing, but I don't find them.

**UPDATE:**
According to @PeterCordes's comments, the @ha and @l should be the correct ones in GCC. 
@ha The “a” part of @ha takes care of sign extension.@h doesn't have sign extension.

Comment: When you compile a program that uses those with Green Hills' compiler, and then disassemble it with `objdump`, what output do you get?

Comment: I don't believe this is an opcode.  The usages google finds for me are of the form `addis   r4,r0,%hiadj(0xFFF48008)`.  Such being the case, I'm expecting them to be "assembly time" computations on hard coded values.

Comment: Have you looked at GCC output for code that accesses global variables, or returns a large constant, to see what syntax GCC (the compiler itself) feeds to GAS?  https://godbolt.org/ has PowerPC GCC installed so you can see the asm output.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, I just saw the code and don't have the Green hills compiler license. I am trying to find one license . If I got any objdump, I will update here.Thanks

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I agree, I checked that is operators from the compiler, finally they will convert to some assemble , I will find out and update here.

Comment: @PeterCordes These code are for Greenhills compiler, the GCC will not work, so there is no GCC output. I will findout the Greenhills output.

Comment: I meant *compile* some C functions *to* GAS-syntax asm.  Not using the `gcc` front-end to run GAS on existing asm source files.

Comment: Looks like it's explained [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.vxworks/zWH2Gq_pNbw) (edited): *PPC860 is a RISC CPU that has one 32 bit word per instruction; the largest constant value you can load into a register is 16 bits because the remainder of the bits are needed to encode the instruction. to load a 32 bit constant requires load+shift and add. PPC add is a signed operation. HIADJ() obtains the upper half of the 32 bit constant, but it also compensates for the sign of the lower half so the addition that is expected to follow will result in the correct value being used.*

Comment: @PeterCordes I got your idea but %hiadj(value) doesn't work in GAS, syntax error. that operator is from greenhills compiler.  I will update the post with my findings.

Comment: Apparently you don't get my idea because you're still talking about getting GAS to assemble `%hiadj(symbol)`.  I told you to look look at GCC's asm *output* from compiling C to asm, because it knows how to create asm that GAS can assemble. I just tried it since I was curious myself what the right syntax is:  https://godbolt.org/z/SEjQHf.  To put the address of a global in a register, GCC4.8.5 uses `lis 3,glob@ha` / `la 3,glob@l(3)`.

Comment: @PeterCordes , wow, that's what I am looking to do . I was going to wrong direction. 
 According to your comments, the "@ha" and "@l" should be the correct answer. Thank you so much.